# How to set the default date for the Date picker in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Below code is working properl. But I don't know how to set the default date value!

```
final dateFormat = DateFormat("dd-M-yyyy");

DateTimePickerFormField(
    dateOnly: true,
    format: dateFormat,
    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Select Date'),
    initialDate: DateTime.now(),
    onSaved: (value){
        _date = value;
    },
),
```

I'm using `datetime_picker_formfield:` flutter library.

I'm trying to do that with `initialDate: DateTime.now()` initial date property but it was not displaying anything as an initial value.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean it is not showing in the `DatePicker` itself? Or before opening te `DatePicker`?

Comment: It is showing the `DatePicker`, Initially it's value is empty. And I want to set the  default value. Later if the user want then he can change the date according to his need!

Comment: and the default value should be today's date!

Comment: What happens if you don't set `initialDate`?

Comment: It works fine I not set the initialDate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Order to show the initial date Value you need to Use - `initialValue:`

`initialDate:` is for the Data Picker to show the Mentioned Date.

```
DateTimePickerFormField(
            dateOnly: true,
            format: dateFormat,
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Select Date'),
            initialValue: DateTime.now(), //Add this in your Code.
            // initialDate: DateTime(2017),
            onSaved: (value) {
              debugPrint(value.toString());
            },
          ),
```

Updated Code with Validator:

```
  var _myKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final dateFormat = DateFormat("dd-M-yyyy");
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Form(
          key: _myKey,
          child: Center(
            child: DateTimePickerFormField(
              dateOnly: true,
              format: dateFormat,
              validator: (val) {
                if (val != null) {
                  return null;
                } else {
                  return 'Date Field is Empty';
                }
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Select Date'),
              initialValue: DateTime.now(), //Add this in your Code.
              // initialDate: DateTime(2017),
              onSaved: (value) {
                debugPrint(value.toString());
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            if (_myKey.currentState.validate()) {
              _myKey.currentState.save();
            } else {
            }
          },
          child: Text('Submit'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: One more query. How to check whether the date is set or not? for validation purpose

Comment: Many Thanks you made my day

Comment: How do I set the initialValue when it's a TimeOfDay?

Answer (score 0):

Change onSaved: to onChanged: and add setState

```
onChanged: (selectedDate) {
    setState(() {
      _properties.gameDateTime = selectedDate;
    });
  },
```